# The error message "Unable to obtain exclusive access to record” is not translated

Tags: error-messages, translation, standard

**"Unable to obtain exclusive access to record”** is a Salesforce Standard error message that appears (in our case) when two persons are editing the same Account. The problem is that even if the language is set to German from User's Setting, the message still appear in English **(it is not translated).**

Is there any chance to translate this error message or Salesforce has to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: If you've found a missing translation, definitely report it to Salesforce Technical Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=translatable_customizations.htm&type=0 looks like Salesforce's out-of-the-box error messages cannot be translated.

```
  You can translate the following components.
  
>     Action
>     Address Country
>     Address State
>     Apex Sharing Reason
>     App
>     Button and Link Label
>     Chatter Extension
>     Custom Field
>     Custom Report Type
>     Data Category
>     Data Category Group
>     Division
>     Feed Filter
>     Field Set
>     Flow
>     Global Value Set
>     Layout Section
>     Lookup Filter
>     Managed Content Node Type
>     Managed Content Type
>     Navigation Menu Item (for Experience Cloud sites)
>     Path Step Rich Text
>     Picklist Value
>     Prompt
>     Prompt Version
>     Record Type
>     Reputation Level (for Experience Cloud sites)
>     S-Control
>     Solution Category
>     Stamp
>     Standard Field Help
>     Validation Error Message
>     Web Tab (also includes Lightning component and Visualforce tabs)
>     Workflow Task
```

Recommend posting your ask as an Idea on Salesforce [IdeaExchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) so that the Product Development team can consider implementing it in coming releases.

Comment: Thank you very much!